# Is it possible to get the entire output of a Powershell command before sending it down the pipe?

Tags: powershell, pipe, pipeline

A command outputs multiple lines of string, and I want to determine if any of those lines matches a string I'm looking for.

Example:

`Get-ChildItem | Select -ExpandProperty "Name" | %{ $_ -Match "Desktop" }` returns false for each folder except for the one named "Desktop".

Is it possible simply return one `True` if any of those folders have "Desktop" in its name, and one `False` otherwise? I'm thinking something like:

`Get-ChildItem | Select -ExpandProperty "Name" | <aggregate_cmdlet> | %{ $_ -Match "Desktop" }`

Comment: Do you mean `Get-ChildItem | Select -ExpandProperty "Name" | %{ $_ -Match "Desktop" } | <aggregate_cmdlet>`? If not, then what do you want to do with the aggregate value in the middle of the pipeline?

Comment: I want `Get-ChildItem` to finish before continuing down the pipe so I can `-Match` every string at once. The answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27726137/2687324 might clarify what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `-match` operator on the entire resulting collection:

```
$ci = Get-ChildItem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Name"
$ci -match "Desktop"
```

Now, the last statement will return all strings that match "Desktop". If no match is found, nothing is returned.

So now we can do (in PowerShell 3.0 and above):

```
$ci -match "Desktop" -as [bool]
```

and have it return `True` when one or more items match "Desktop".

And in one-liner format:

```
(ls|select -exp Name)-match"Desktop"-as[bool]
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to get what you want is -

```
(Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.Name -ieq 'Desktop'}).Length -gt 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you changed your `ForEach-Object` into a `Where-Object` you would have another approach to what you are looking for. Currently `Get-ChildItem | Select -ExpandProperty "Name" | %{ $_ -Match "Desktop" }` is just outputting the value of the value to output. Lets capture the results into a variable and a simple `If` will evaluate if there are any matches.

```
$results = Get-ChildItem | Select -Expand "Name" | ?{ $_ -Match "Desktop" }
If($results){
    Write-Host "there is at least 1 match"
}
```

This could be simplified by removing the variable altogehter however I would suspect you need to work with the results. It is included nonetheless.

```
If(Get-ChildItem | Select -Expand "Name" | ?{ $_ -Match "Desktop" }){
    Write-Host "there is at least 1 match"
}
```

We can take this one step further with `-Filter`

```
If(Get-ChildItem -Filter "Desktop" }){
    Write-Host "there is at least 1 match"
}
```